# How to perform diffsception (diffing intermediary diff outputs together to filter out irrelevant changes)

Tags: linux, filtering, diff, hexdump, memory-dump

So I've got 4 memory dumps from an emulator running a game in 2 different but similar scenarios, with 2 dumps taken seconds apart in each scenario. What I'm looking to do is filter out things that change all the time to get a much cleaner and more concise final diff between the 2 scenarios, I'd like to be able to run a diff between the 2 dumps from one scenario to filter out constantly changing values, do the same for the other scenario, then diff the outputs of the "filtered" dumps.

I tried doing it all with just `hexdump` and `diff` but the final diff file was 133k lines long, and larger then the 2 intermediary diffs...
What I did was:

```
> (diff -y <(hexdump 1A.dump) <(hexdump 1B.dump)) > 1.diff
> (diff -y <(hexdump 2A.dump) <(hexdump 2B.dump)) > 2.diff
> (diff -y 1.diff 2.diff) > Final.diff
```

or in one line: `(diff -y <(diff -y <(hexdump 1A.dump) <(hexdump 1B.dump)) <(diff -y <(hexdump 2A.dump) <(hexdump 2B.dump))) > Final.diff`

I realize now that this is ***definitely*** not how `diff` works, and there's probably a very good reason why it didn't work, but I don't particularly understand the output of this tool so I'd like to know where exactly I went wrong, thanks in advance~!